# Jquery/PHP : How do I load any html content by id/class from another website

Tags: php, jquery, html, load

Im trying to run a script for a project, the goal is simple :

My only issue is i can't find any way to get the number of result google find when you make research. For example you search for "game" on google and it shows xxxx results load in xx sec. My script would be something like :

- An input : for the word/expression you want to know number of result
- A div/p/span : for display the number of result got from google

If any one has any clue on how to do that, with javascript if possible, jquery if javascript is not enought, and in the end PHP if really jquery can't.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

term called ***CROSS DOMAIN***

1. PHP : **[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)** is the solution.
2. jQuery : use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: I dont get how jsonp work, im gonna try with php curl function, thanks ^-^